# AWS Step Function - Adding dynamic value to Pass state type

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I have the following state defined in my state machine.

```
 "loop":{
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result":{
        "totalCount": "$.newFieldsResponse.body.count",
        "currentCount": 0,
        "step": 1
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.iteration",
      "Next":"iterateLoop"
    },
```

I expect the output of the state to be:

```
"newFieldsResponse": {
      "isSuccess": true,
      "error": "",
      "body": {
        "count": 2,
        "fields": [...]
      }
    },
    "iteration": {
      "totalCount": 5,
      "currentCount": 0,
      "step": 1
    }
  }
```

iteration property is added to the input with totalCount property to be set to count of items in fields array.

However, the output for "iteration" property is set as:

```
"iteration": {
      "totalCount": "$.newFieldsResponse.body.count",
      "currentCount": 0,
      "step": 1
    }
```

It looks like the value "$.newFieldsResponse.body.count" is not getting resolved and is output as is.

Is there something I am doing wrong ? Can someone please advice on how to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this may not be possible.
The workaround I did is to use "Parameters" property. From AWS documentation:
"For key-value pairs where the value is selected using a path, the key name must end in *.$. ".

So resolved the above by :

1. Changing Pass state to remove any dynamic value reference

```
"loop":{
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result":{
        "currentCount": 0,
        "step": 1
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.iteration",
      "Next":"iterateLoop"
    },
```

2. creating a Parameters property where I need the values as below:

```
 "iterateLoop":{
      "Type":"Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:....r",
      "Parameters":{
        "totalCount.$": "$.newFieldsResponse.body.count",
        "currentCount.$": "$.iteration.currentCount",
        "step.$": "$.iteration.step"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.iteration",
      "Next":"continueLoop"
    },
```

totalCount, currentCount and step all read the value from using a path in the state input. The key needs to be appended with a ".$" at the end.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html

Answer (score 13):

This is possible through ["Parameters"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html) in [pass state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html)

> **JSON**

```
{
  "loop": {
    "Type": "Pass",
    "Parameters": {
      "totalCount": "$.newFieldsResponse.body.count",
      "currentCount": 0,
      "step": 1
    },
    "ResultPath": "$.iteration",
    "Next": "iterateLoop"
  }
}
```

Comment: `"totalCount"` need to change to `"totalCount.$"` for me

Answer (score 11):

It works in a combination of two of the solutions here exposed:

1. Add Parameter in Pass step
2. Add *.$ in the name of the var you want to pass:

```
 {
  "loop": {
    "Type": "Pass",
    "parameters": {
      "totalCount.$": "$.newFieldsResponse.body.count",
      "currentCount": 0,
      "step": 1
    },
    "ResultPath": "$.iteration",
    "Next": "iterateLoop"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I too got stuck on this before I figured it out.

Pass states can be used, but @ankitkanojia and @shashi 's answers need a minor modification.

If you want to use input paths, the keys inside parameters need to end in ".$" ("totalCount.$")

So the state specification should be as follows:

```
"loop":{
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result":{
        "totalCount.$": "$.newFieldsResponse.body.count",
        "currentCount": 0,
        "step": 1
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.iteration",
      "Next":"iterateLoop"
    },
```